# Meaning of absent <target> element in XLIFF

Tags: xliff

According to ["A. XLIFF Tree Structure" of XLIFF Specification 1.2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#AppTree) `<trans-unit>` element always has a single `<source>` element but can have 0 or 1 `<target>` element. Yet nowhere in the specification I found an explanation what would the absence of `<target>` element mean? Would it mean that translation is an empty string or that translation is the same text as contained in `<source>` element?

And in what part of specification (or some other source) that meaning is explained?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for the absence of `<target>` element and they can be different in various implementation of XLIFF format.
[Sdl Trados Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDL_Trados) uses missing `<target>` elements in units with `translate="no"` attribute (defined in Xliff namespace) - e.g. when source contains only tags.
It could also mean that the translation unit is not segmented yet, but as I said I think it depends on implementation.

Comment: I am more interested to know what the authors of the XLIFF spec meant when they allowed <target> element to be missing (regardless of how different TMS treat the XLIFF spec in their software).

Comment: Newly-created XLIFF files that have not yet been translated also sometimes don't contain `<target>` information.  When there's no target, it simply means that there is text extracted from the source document that has no translation yet.